# PHP/Ajax - Sending a JQuery value to a PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having diffiiculty with this as I'm following on from somebody elses code, if somebody could help me with this I would appreciate it.

Basically I have a Jqgrid that displays a list of bookings, when you double click a row it opens a jqdialog that displays all the details about their booking.

I have a variable defined which is the booking reference which I want to pass to a php script.

```
var brData = rowData['bookref'];
```

I am then trying to send this via ajax:

```
function getGridRow(brData) {

$.ajax({

    // Request sent from control panel, so send to cp.request.php (which is the handler)
    url: 'scripts/php/bootstrp/all.request.php',
    type: 'POST',

    data: {

        ft: "getDGRow",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'fnme=getDGRow&row_data='+brData,
        //row_data: rowData,


        id: null,
        condition: null
    },
    dataType: 'xml',
    timeout: 20000,
    error: function(){
        $('#cp-div-error').html('');
        $('#cp-div-error').append('<p>There was an error inserting the data, please try again later.</p>');
        $('#cp-div-error').dialog('open');
    },
    success: function(response){


    }
});
```

this is the case in all.request.php:

```
case 'getDGRow':
header('Content-type: text/xml');
DatagridController::getGridRow($_REQUEST['row_data']);
break;
```

and this is where I want to pass the variable 'brData':

```
public static function getGridRow($row_data) {


    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$row_data'";
```

I'm finding this very confusing at the moment, so any help would be much appreciated. At the moment $row_data is my php function is blank so obviously it isn't selecting any row from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with verifying that the javascript function is not passing a blank variable. Try alerting the variable "brData". Second, verify if the ajax call is successful, probably by the use of firebug's console. Third, make sure that the PHP receives it and can enter the function. You may try

```
public static function getGridRow($row_data) {
    echo $row_data;
    exit;
}
```

in your PHP file and alert the value in your html.

```
function getGridRow(brData) {
    $.ajax({
        //...blah blah blah
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

If you can receive an alert from your scripts, I guess the last thing that you can try is 
query manually to your database using the value of the variable that was sent back to you by your PHP script. Who knows, there really is no result for the produced query.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can confirm that alerting the variable brData alerts the correct value and that the ajax call is successful as I have put response = brData; in the success function and this returns the correct value. The value is not being passed to the getGridRow function as echo $row_data doesn't return anything. Any idea why?

Comment: It's a good thing that you found where the problem starts. You need to use a debugger from that point, check if the function is being called or if the variable passed to the function is already null.

Comment: Okay, I have changed the ajax request to 'GET', and in my getGridRow function I have tested and put echo $rowdata; which returns the correct row but it is still not selecting all the bookings where row is equal to the bookingreference. $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'";, at this point $rowdata is empty, but if I echo $rowdata at the start of this function it gives me the correct booking reference number... any ideas?